# Menu list with choices

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a choice list in a program and now I'm stuck with what happens when user writes incorrect input.

I've tried doing it with *do* loop (I've looped switch statement). Also, tried to set variable *key* to integer and char, but both have problems. *Char* only takes one character and when you write more than one it starts checking every by itself. Using *int* I get an infinite loop of *menu* function when inputting incorrectly.

Also, tried using *cin.fail()*, which I've found here, in stackoverflow, but it didn't work out.

```
void menu()
{
if(!isEmpty())
{
    showStack();
}
else
{
    cout << "stekas tuscias!" << endl;
}

cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
cout << "1. Iterpti i steka (push)" << endl;
cout << "2. Pasalinti is steko (pop)" << endl;
cout << "3. Issaugoti steka" << endl;
cout << "4. Issaugoti steka ir uzdaryti programa" << endl;
cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
cout << "Jusu pasirinkimas: ";

char key;
cin >> key;
switch(key)
{
    case '1':
    {
        cout << "Irasykite reiksme i konsole: ";
        int data;
        cin >> data;
        cout << endl;
        push(data);
        break;
    }
    case '2':
    {
        cout << endl;
        pop();
        break;
    }
    case '3':
    {
        write();
        cout << "--------" << endl;
        cout << "Stekas issaugotas!" << endl;
        cout << "--------" << endl;
        menu();
        break;
    }
    case '4':
    {
        write();
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        cout << "Tokio pasirinkimo nera!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        key = '\0';
        menu();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

My whole code if it's needed: https://pastebin.com/Xv1HE0Mh

Comment: Using a loop instead of recursion is probably a good start in any case.

Comment: Usage of recursion is a very. very, very bad idea here.

Comment: It's fine: tailrec optimization. (yes, this is a joke)

Comment: As for your problems with the input, if you use `char` (like in the code shown) then remember that input to a `char` will also read the newline you get for pressing the `Enter` key. The infinite loop is because if the wrong input is given, it will not be extracted from the input buffer, and you have to [*ignore*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) that yourself, as well as [*clear*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the flags.

Comment: So what happens?  Did you put a breakpoint in and step through and see line by line why everything is happening?

Comment: 1) "_My whole code if it's needed:_" The "whole" code is rarely needed. One should provide [mcve] instead of snippets, though. 2) What's wrong with any variant of `int x; if (std::cin >> x) {/* Do Processing */} else { /* invalid input; reset the state of std::cin*/ }` pattern?

Comment: I didn't know you need to reset the state of cin, but now with your help I've managed to do that. Thank you

Comment: @EdvinasSadeckas If the question has been answered, please add the right answer.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yeah, but he did provide it optionally. Doesn't really hsrm anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-catch-throw block. Use decltype or typeof feature to see if the input is an integer.

Comment: "decltype or typeof feature to see if the input is an integer"> How could that possibly work?

Comment: @SeanBurton Shouldn't it? Not decltype, but is_same <> ::value maybe?

Comment: The type of the variable is fixed when it is declared, *before* cin is used to read anything into it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure why cin.fail() or (!cin) isn't working for you. But, you can do this. And, I'm also sure this kind of question exists.

```
template <class T>
int check (T ch)
{
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'Z') return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

And, then.

```
main ()
{
.
.
char c;
cin.get (c); //Note here!!
if (check (c)) {...}
else {...} //You can use goto.
.
}
```